# trouble with parsing strings

Tags: java

i have a string:

```
String value = "(name) Says: hello (/name)";
```

where "name" could also be "lastName", "address" "postalCode" or many many other things.

i split the string on the "(" 
i want to also split on the ")" ... however, some strings will only contain the following:

```
String value = "(name Says: hello (/name)";
```

my problem is that the string content could also contain ")" and "(" so how would i parse this then? For instance:

```
String value = "(name Says: can you solve for y = (x-b)? (/name)";
```

the string could also be as follows:

```
String value = "(name)Says: can you solve for y = (x-b)? (/name)";
```

**OR**

```
String value = "(name) Says: can you solve for y = (x-b)?(/name)";
```

**OR**

```
String value = "(name)Says: can you solve for y = (x-b)?(/name)";
```

i was initially thinking that i could do a count of how many ")" there are in a string. However, if there are more than 2, i'm not sure what i should do? The reason why i would need to know how many ")" there are in a string is because i want to isolate "name"

any ideas? (i don't want to use any libraries, just want to come up with the **logic** )...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question wasn't very clear to me. However,as far as I could understand,I guess that you want to capture the name and also the sentence that follows it,both seperately.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Here's the solution:
1.Parse your String until the first space after "(" .

2.Store it in a temp String. Its length is given by `temp.length()`.

3.So check if `temp.charAt(temp.length()-1)==')'`.

4.If yes then name would be in the substring `temp.substring(1,temp.length()-2)`.

5.Otherwise it would be in the substring `temp.substring(1,temp.length()-1)`.

6.Now the value after name can be stored in another `String` until you find `"(/"`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Extract all characters after the first space and before the last space.

Comment: thanks for the response, that would work, unfortunately i forgot to mention, the space after the ")" isn't always there... +1 for the thought/help though

Comment: Then check if the string starts with "(name". If not, abort. If so, check if it starts with "(name)". If so, take everything after the first `)` but before the last `(`. If not, take everything after the first `e` but before the last `(`.

Answer (score 1):

below code will return name in both of your condition:

```
String s = "(name Says: can you solve for y = (x-b)? (/name)";
int firstIndex = s.indexOf("(");
int secondIndex = s.indexOf(":");
int thirdIndex = 0;
String name = "";
if(s.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex).contains(")")) {
    thirdIndex = s.indexOf(")");
} else {
    thirdIndex = s.indexOf(" ");
}

System.out.println("(name) or (name : "+s.substring(firstIndex+1, thirdIndex));
String temp = s.substring(thirdIndex+1, s.length());
System.out.println(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("(/")));
System.out.println("(/name) : "+ temp.substring(temp.indexOf("(/")+2, temp.lastIndexOf(")")));
```

Answer (score 1):

First parse last symbols while you will not find "(/string)"
Then get all that you have between "(/" and ")" except spaces at the edges.
And try to find in the beginning of the line kind of this construction "(" + name.trim() + ")" with or without ")"

Besides java.util.regex.* must be your best friend in this situation.